# Javafx Slider event listener being called before it snaps to the nearest tick

Tags: java, javafx, slider

I am trying to update some information every time the `Slider` value is changed, so I have the code set up like this:

```
int betAmount = 0;
Slider betSlider = new Slider();
betSlider.setMinorTickCount(4);
betSlider.setMajorTickUnit(250);
betSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);

betSlider.valueChangingProperty().addListener((obs, wasChanging, isChanging) -> {
    if (!isChanging) {
        betAmount = (int) betSlider.getValue();
        update(); //update method, not relevant to problem
    }
});
```

The problem that I am having is that the `getValue()` method on my slider is being called before it snaps to the nearest tick. Because of this, I am getting the incorrect value stored in my `betAmount` variable. I was wondering if there was any way to get the slider's value after it has finished snapping to the nearest tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `valueProperty()` in place of `valueChangingProperty()`

```
betSlider.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
       betAmount = newValue.intValue());
});
```

`valueChanging` -> It provides notification that the value is changing.

`value` -> The current value represented by this Slider.

Comment: Is there a way to make this not get called every time the value is moved, but only when it has stopped moving?

Comment: @camelsaucerer what does your code look like now please?

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this in the past is to use the slider's valueProperty() and filter out any new values that occur while the slider is still changing.

```
int betAmount = 0;
Slider betSlider = new Slider();
betSlider.setMinorTickCount(4);
betSlider.setMajorTickUnit(250);
betSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);

betSlider.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue) && !betSlider.isValueChanging()) {
        betAmount = newValue.intValue();
        update(); //update method, not relevant to problem
    }
});
```